# Is there a database of known riboswitches?

Tags: rna, database

I'm looking for sequences and annotations of known riboswitches, but so far I haven't found a resource that actually fulfills my requirements. The best database I found so far is Rfam, which has entries for many riboswitch classes. The biggest drawbacks of Rfam for my case are that it doesn't contain any information about the expression platform, only about the aptamer. I'd like to know if a riboswitch is translational or transcriptional, and where the terminator/Shine-Dalgarno sequences that are regulated by the switch are. Another limitation of Rfam is that I can't easily see which sequences are validated biologically in some way, and which are just predicted.

Is there a database of riboswitches that also contains information about the expression platform?